# Graphics.py circles glitching when bouncing off each other

Tags: python, graphics

I have finished creating a code that makes circles bounce off of each other and the walls they are in. I used graphics.py and have worked on making the code shorter and more elegant. It works well but the circles frequently glitch when they bounce off of each other. This was not a problem with my longer code. What could be causing this? Thank you :)

```
from graphics import*
from random import*
from time import*
from math import sqrt

win = GraphWin('My Program', 600, 600)
win.setBackground('springgreen3')

holidays = Text(Point(300, 100), 'Happy Holidays!!!')
holidays.setStyle('bold italic')
holidays.draw(win)

class mycircle:
    circle = ''
    vel_x = 0
    vel_y = 0
    circle_fill = ''
    circle_outline = ''

    def __init__(self, circle, vel_x, vel_y, circle_fill, circle_outline):
        self.circle = circle
        self.vel_x = vel_x
        self.vel_y = vel_y
        self.circle.setFill(circle_fill)
        self.circle.setOutline(circle_outline)
        self.circle.draw(win)

circle1 = mycircle(Circle(Point(100,100),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'tan2', 'red')
circle2 = mycircle(Circle(Point(300,200),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'tan2', 'red')
circle3 = mycircle(Circle(Point(400,300),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'tan2', 'red')
circle4 = mycircle(Circle(Point(500,400),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'red2', 'red')
circle5 = mycircle(Circle(Point(300,500),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'red2', 'red')
circle6 = mycircle(Circle(Point(150,250),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'red2', 'red')
circle7 = mycircle(Circle(Point(25,250),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'green', 'red')
circle8 = mycircle(Circle(Point(350,35),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'green', 'red')
circle9 = mycircle(Circle(Point(45,450),30), randint(-8,8), randint(-8,-8), 'green', 'red')

allcircles = [circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4, circle5, circle6, circle7, circle8, circle9]

key = win.checkKey()
while key == '':

    for c in allcircles:
        c.circle.move(c.vel_x, c.vel_y)
        sleep(0.000000001)

        find_center = c.circle.getCenter()
        center_x = find_center.getX()
        center_y = find_center.getY()

        if ((center_x - 30) <= 0) or ((center_x + 30) >= 600):
            c.vel_x = -c.vel_x

        if ((center_y - 30) <= 0) or ((center_y + 30) >= 600):
            c.vel_y = -c.vel_y

        def circleDistance(cir1, cir2):
            center1 = cir1.getCenter()
            center2 = cir2.getCenter()
            x1 = center1.getX()
            y1 = center1.getY()
            x2 = center2.getX()
            y2 = center2.getY()
            dist = sqrt((x2-x1) * (x2-x1) + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1))
            return dist

        newlist = allcircles.copy()
        newlist.remove(c)

        for d in newlist:
            if circleDistance(d.circle, c.circle) <= 60:
                d.vel_x = -d.vel_x
                d.vel_y = -d.vel_y

    key = win.checkKey()
```

Comment: What do you mean by glitch

Comment: Instead of bouncing right away it will do a motion like a double bounce. Sometimes it bounces right away but it frequently does this.

Comment: The physics you are using is flawed, the direction of the velocity components perpendicular to the tangent passing by the point of contact should be negated. It requires the appropriate calculations to be done. Not that you can't do it with some effort and dealing with glitches like these, it's just that is is much simpler to use a physics engine such as box2d https://pypi.org/project/Box2D/

Comment: Another note: Copying the list each time and removing the current circle is not efficient nor elegant. Just loop over the circles again and only act if the `c is not c2` (not the same object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It double bounce because a collision has been detected then the velocities have been changed. However, before it gets out of collision range it detects another collision (distance still less than 60) and changes the velocity again.